# Cannot read property 'create' of undefined guild

Tags: discord.js

```
client.guilds.cache.get('<id>').channel.create(message.author.username, 'text');
```

I'm trying to use this code here to create a text channel titled with the message author's username, but I can't get the specified server (the ID is correct).

Comment: The error states that `channel` is undefined. What does `client.guilds.cache.get()` return? You can simply `console.log` it.

Comment: It returns undefined, even though the guild id should be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a channel, you need the [GuildChannelManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager) of a guild. To get this, you need to call the [`Guild.channels`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=channels) property. Instead you have `.channel` without the `s` at the end. Try using `.get('<id>').channels.create` and see how that works.